# switching from getchar to fgets

Tags: c, while-loop, fgets, getchar

I am trying to switching my use of getchar to fgets but, when using getchar, the entire code does not work.

```
//fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);

  while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin))
  {
   portNum[sizeof(line)] = (char)line;
  }

while((c = getchar()) != '\n')
{
    portNum[num++] = c;
}
portNum[num] = '\0';
```

How can I make equal for those two functions to work properly?

Comment: For `fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)` the second argument is the`Maximum number of characters to be copied into str (including the terminating null-character).`. Give it a defined value. Also, `fgets` will keep on reading until a newline is encountered. No need of the while loop.

Comment: `portNum[sizeof(line)] = (char)line;`  do you have any idea of what you're doing?

Answer (score 1):

You usage of `fgets` is wrong.

> `fgets` Reads characters from stream and stores them as a C string into str until (num-1) characters have been read or either a newline or the end-of-file is reached, whichever happens first.

In your case `fgets` will read all the characters until newline is encountered.

Also, the parameters usage is wrong.

> char * fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream );
>
> str => Pointer to an array of chars where the string read is copied.
>
> num => Maximum number of characters to be copied into str (including the
>   terminating null-character).
>
> stream => Pointer to a FILE object that identifies an input stream.
>   stdin can be used as argument to read from the standard input.

Refer to the `fgets` documentation for more information.

[fgets man page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/)

Answer (score 1):

OP's `fgets()` usage is unclear and `portNum[sizeof(line)] = (char)line;` is certainly in error.

Instead: how to make the below `getchar()` code more `fgets()`-like:

```
// assumed missing code
#define N 100
int c;
char portNum[N];
size_t num = 0;

// size and EOF detection added (which should have been there)
while(num + 1 < sizeof portnum && (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {  
    portNum[num++] = c;
}
portNum[num] = '\0';

// assumed missing code
if (c == EOF && num == 0) Handle_EndOfFile_or_InputError();
else ...
```

This can be replaced with `fgets()` code

```
#define N 100
char portNum[N+1]; // 1 larger for the \n

if (fgets(portNum, sizeof portNum, stdin)) {
  // lop off potential trailing \n
  portNum[strcspn(portNum, "\n")] = '\0';
  ...
} else {
  Handle_EndOfFile_or_InputError();
}
```